# Getting last N segments of URL in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I need to write a function to return the last N segments of a given URL, i.e. given **/foo/bar/zoo** and `N=2`, I expect to get back **/bar/zoo**. Boundary conditions should be handled appropriately. I have no problem doing it in C, but the best C++ version I could come up is this:

```
string getLastNSegments(const string& url, int N)
{
    basic_string<char>::size_type found = 0, start = path.length()+1;

    int segments = 2;
    while (start && segments && (start = path.find_last_of('/', start-1)) != string::npos) {
        found = start;
        segments--;
    }

return url.substr(found);
}

cout << "result: " << getLastNSegments("/foo/bar/zoo", 2) << endl;
```

Is there a more idiomatic (STL+algorithms) way of doing this?

Comment: First of all, change `basic_string<char>` into `string` :)

Comment: I think the line `int segments = 2;` should read `int segments = N;`

Comment: Yes, that was an oversight, should be `int segments = N`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) and [`rfind()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/).

You call `rfind` successively `N` times feeding the last index as parameter. You now have the start index of the string you're looking for and use `substr` to extract the substring.

```
std::string x("http:/example.org/a/b/abc/bcd");
int N = 3;
int idx = x.length();
while ( idx >= 0 && --N > 0 )
{
   idx = x.rfind('/',idx) - 1;
}
std::string final = x.substr(idx);
```

Comment: How is that different from using `find_last_of()`, except for the specification of the character to be found?

Comment: You still need to check that you haven't gone past the beginning of the string and that you got the right number of segments. Which is what my example is doing, except with `find_last_of()`. If you could post an example for `rfind()`, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Running your example with `N = 2` gives me `c/bcd` instead of the expected `/abc/bcd`.

Comment: @andrei do some debugging, I pointed out the general idea. Haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with just using a loop..  Don't know of any STL string functions that will do what you want in a single call.

By the way, what happens when You ask for the last 3 segments of `http://www.google.com/`?

Call me old-school, but personally I would not use any STL searches here...  What's the matter with this:

```
if( N <= 0 || url.length() == 0 ) return "";

const char *str = url.c_str();
const char *start = str + url.length();
int remain = N;

while( --start != str )
{
    if( *start == '/' && --remain == 0 ) break;
}

return string(start);
```

Answer (score 0):

Last but not least, a simple boost split solution

```
string getLastNSegments(const string& url, int n)
{
    string selected;
    vector<string> elements;
    boost::algorithm::split(elements, url, boost::is_any_of("/"));

    for (int i = 0; i < min(n, int(elements.size())); i++)
        selected = "/" + elements.at(elements.size()-1-i) + selected;

    return selected;
}
```